# Use streambuf as buffer for boost asio read and write

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, boost-asio, streambuf

I'm using this code for reading

```
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

and this for writing

```
boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
    boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
    boost::bind(&session::handle_write, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

where socket_ is socket, max_length is enum with value 1024 and data_ is char array with length of max_length.

But I want to replace char array buffer with streambuf. I've tried

```
  boost::asio::streambuf streamBuffer;
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(streamBuffer),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

But isn't working. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to get a [`mutable_buffers_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf/mutable_buffers_type.html) from the `streambuf` to use as your first parameter to `async_read_some`.

```
  boost::asio::streambuf streamBuffer;
  boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type mutableBuffer =
      streamBuffer.prepare(max_length);
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mutableBuffer),
        boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

See the `asio` documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf.html) and [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) for more info.